# Android public SOAP call for a private web server

Tags: java, android, oracle, soap, redirect

There is a oracle web service in my company's private server(Allowed only VPN and APNs) should be accessed from public android app. So at this moment I can not imagine a way to do my SOAP call. I have done it in android emulator(which was on my office pc) but now my company asks me to do it on normal public android device. So I'm being thankful here if some one suggest me some new ideas. Thank you. (I'm a junior android developer and not an expert on servers.)

Comment: there are android based VPN apps available, get any one of'em, get connected to you office VPN then your server and your android device would be on same network

Comment: @ppuskar Thanks.. But it's difficult to install a VPN app for all phones we wanted to run our app. Is'nt it..?

Comment: atleast you can do this http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/smartphones/connect-to-a-pptp-vpn-from-your-android-phone/

all android based smartphones have this feature :)

Comment: It is possible to configure a VPN programatically inside your android app, but it is not easy as the 'service' required is internal and hidden.
If you keep searching on here, you will find solutions allowing you to first configure the VPN, then use it, within your application.

Answer (score 1):

If it's an app just for you or for internal employees that all have VPN access, the easiest way to go is to use a VPN in the phone. You'll have to teach everyone to configure the VPN. It's also the most secure one if the private server holds sensitive information.

If it's an app you plan to release to the big public, or having everyone install a VPN is not an option, you could do this: Get another server that's reachable from the outside but can access the VPN, and in it make another service that passes service calls to the internal server.

Anyway, it doesn't make much sense, for a public app, that its server is inside a VPN.

Comment: Thanks.. We have decided already to use another IP (and allow it to connect to company server) to do our web service calls. It can be done. But can you explain is it practically a good solution..?